# Use NGINX rewrite variable as array of chars?

Tags: image, nginx, migration, prestashop, directory

So after migration from pretashop 1.4 -> 1.6 all images folders structure move from /img/p/*-*.jpg to /img/p/*/*/*/*...

In same products description we have image links to old structure and I just want to make rule.

Exmaple old structure: /img/p/1256-5097.jpg

From this url I can get id 5097, but to use it in new image foldes I neet to split it to img/p/5/0/9/7/5097.jpg

Can I get(split) id using just nginx rewrite module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rewrite` directive uses regular expressions. Specify a regular expression that captures the digits individually, then rebuild the URI as required, for example:

```
rewrite ^(/img/p/)\d+-(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(.jpg)$ $1$2/$3/$4/$5/$2$3$4$5$6;
```

It looks horrible, but it breaks down as:

```
$1 = /img/p/
$2 = 5
$3 = 0
$4 = 9
$5 = 7
$6 = .jpg
```

You do not need to capture `$1` and `$6`, these could be hard-coded into the result.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for `rewrite` syntax, and [this useful resource](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html) for regular expressions.

Comment: Thx. IT was my first thought to use it with (\d). Working well just change it a bit to other rules.